# Array constructor and array initialization - gnu fortran vs intel fortran

Tags: visual-studio-2008, fortran, codeblocks, gfortran, intel-fortran

This subroutine does exactly what it is written and was writen in Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 and compiled with Intel Fortran. No errors. It works perfectly.

```
subroutine linspace(x,xi,xo,n)
! This subroutine generates a linearly spaced vector
! of n elements between xi and xo.
!   call linspace(x,xi,xo,n)

    ! input variables
    double precision, intent(in) :: xi, xo
    integer, intent(in) :: n

    ! output variables
    double precision, allocatable, intent(out) :: x(:)

    ! auxiliar variables
    double precision :: dx

    if (allocated(x)) deallocate( x )
    allocate( x(n) )

    dx = (xo-xi)/(n-1)
    x = xi + [0:n-1]*dx
end subroutine linspace
```

If I copy this code in Code Blocks and try to compile with GNU Fortran, it returns an error in the array declaration:

```
f95:97:15: Error: Syntax error in array constructor at (1)
```

What is a simple workaround to make it work, without having to change too much code? (without a do-loop)

PS: In Visual Studio, I have the impression that this code run faster than using a do-loop.

Comment: To make clear how the related answer applies: `[(xi+i*dx, i=0,n-1)]`.